# How to Triger a css animation for a y element from a a trigger x

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to animate my body background when i hover over a link, can someone help me with that.

I have a animation "myfirst" that changes the background colour,

```
@keyframes myfirst
{
from{background: black;}
to{background: white;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from{ background: black;}
to{background: white;}

}
```

Right now i have made it so that when i hover body the animation is triggered.

```
body:hover{
animation: myfirst 0.01s;
animation-iteration-count:500;
-webkit-animation: myfirst 0.01s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:500;
}
```

I want that a link triggers the animation that changes my bodies background.

Comment: You can't only with CSS ... you can't refer to parents with css selectors

Comment: you could add a click listener on the link and add in js a class which contains the animation

Comment: I'm afraid others are right. It's a cascading style sheet - it rolls down, not up.

Comment: I think it's what they do in this demo: http://codepen.io/Treehouse/pen/mvlEq

Comment: can it be done with js

Comment: @SERPRO But your example uses sibling selectors, what he needs is a parent selector which is impossible in pure CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other's have said, in order to change the `body` when an element is clicked, you'd need to have a parent selector. Since CSS has no parent selector capability, you will have to use a little javascript

```
// Set onclick function for the element you want
document.getElementById('changeBG').onmouseover = function() { 
    document.body.style.animation = "myfirst 0.01s 500"; //Give the body the anim
    // The above could also be done by adding a class with the animation 
    // properties on click
};
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9Ss6/1/)

However, if you only want the background to flash when the link is hovered and to stop otherwise, you could do it in pure CSS using another HTML element (a kind of fake `body`). It requires that the fake-body element follow the link in the document flow like so

```
<a id='changeBG' href='#'>Change background</a>
<div id='cover'></div>
```

and the CSS for that fake-body element

```
#cover {
    position:absolute; /* Don't affect other elements */
    top:0; left:0; /* Fill up the entire viewport */
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1; /* Be placed behind all other elements */
}
```

You would then use a sibling selector (I use `+` which is the directly following sibling) and `:hover` to give the animation to the fake-body

```
#changeBG:hover + #cover {
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 0.01s 500;
    animation: myfirst 0.01s 500;
}
```

[**Demo of that approach**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9Ss6/4/)